# Cannot add guests to a team through Graph API

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to add users to a team that I have created through the Graph API using application permissions, but I run into an issue.

I POST the following object to [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{teamid}/members](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7Bteamid%7D/members):

{"roles":[],"@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember","user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/60d7e7a4-b1f6-4a5a-a9a3-80480156cb31"}

which returns 403 error code for guest users, regardless of if they are pending acceptance or has accepted the invitation. I get the following object returned:

{
"error": {
"code": "Forbidden",
"message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2020-12-17T12:10:54",
"request-id": "16b3d4d7-6295-4cbd-b1bb-3803678947a6",
"client-request-id": "16b3d4d7-6295-4cbd-b1bb-3803678947a6"
}
}
}

It would seem like I might be missing some sort of permission, but I currently have these permission:
Group.ReadWrite.All- Application

OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All - Application

TeamMember.ReadWrite.All - Application

User.Invite.All - Application

User.Read.All - Application

I have no issue when adding a member of the organisation to the team, it works perfectly fine.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is that you must be a **global administrator** or a **team administrator** and **team owner** to add guests to the team, so you must log in as a user with the role of administrator before you can add guest users.

So you can't use the application permission to get the token, because it has no user login, you can use it to add member users, but it cannot be used to add guests. You need to add **TeamMember.ReadWrite.All** `delegates permissions`, and then grants **admin consent**, and then you need to use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain an access token.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I will try it out, I have only worked with application permissions so far. I'm a beginner with Azure in general, are the roles you mentioned roles in Azure? . I haven't tried the solution yet, but I will mark this as the answer as it seems correct to me.

Comment: @tglue   Yes,  is a role in Azure.